Calabi-Yau: Structure Group of $TM$ reduces to $SU(n)$
I have a (maybe trivial) problem concerning the first definition of Calabi-Yau manifolds on Wikipedia: Among others, it says that for a Kähler manifold $M$, the two properties

The structure group of $TM$ can be reduced from $U(n)$ to $SU(n)$
$M$ has a Kähler metric with global holonomy contained in $SU(n)$

are equivalent.
But without having a specific counter-example in mind, it seems to me like the second condition is stronger than the first:
Usually, being able to reduce just the structure group of $TM$ only leads to "almost ..."-manifolds like  almost complex manifold if there is a reduction to $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ or almost symplectic manifold if there is a reduction to $Sp(2n)$.  The integrability needed to get an actual complex/ symplectic manifold morally comes from being able to have a reduction of global holonomy. In this sense, the first property above seems to imply that $M$ is something like an "almost Calabi-Yau"-manifold.
In short:  Why does the second property imply the first?
